# Swiftui Side Menu button action

Tags: button, action, swiftui

I would like to create a side menu i did but i don't know how to add a button actions that take me to new view , 
this is an example about what i want :

Profile button to Profile view

Messages to Message view,

Setting to Setting view

3 different views 

This is my Side Menu Code

```
var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Profile")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 100)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Messages")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Text("Settings")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
                Spacer()
            }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: You could add `.onTap` modifier to each `HStack`

Comment: How ? can you five me a Simple Code

Comment: your snapshot is not enough to demo this, please add minimal testable code that depicts your current environment and where is expected behaviour is absent or does not work.

Comment: Try this library for side menu https://github.com/amirpirzad/TwitterSideMenu